# What is the difference between bond disassociation energy and lattice energy?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Bond disassociation energy refers to amount of energy required to break bonds of one mole of atom of particular type whereas lattice energy is the energy required to separate a crystal lattice containing one mole ions into their respective gaseous states.

What i can understand from the above information is that bond dissociation energy has to be a broader classification and lattice energy must be a subset of it.

Is it true or am i wrong. Please correct me, i am a bit confused.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you speaking of _ionic_ compounds, to begin with? Both terms are much broader than that.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean just that. Bond disassociation energy is not limited to ionic compounds. Neither is lattice energy.

Comment: if you are a senior secondary student (class 11 or 12) like me, then my point may mean some sense-bond disassociation enthalpy is the energy required to break a bond between two atoms of the same molecule while lattice enthalpy is the energy required to overcome the intermolecular forces of attraction between the molecules in a crystalline system ( it may be an ionic or covalent or molecular crystal as @Ivan Neretin quoted.